# "TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function" in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

For the first time in too many months (blush), I upgraded my jQuery stuff.  I'm now on:

- jquery-1.9.1.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js (used ThemeRoller, and included all components, including the Effects Core, which mentions easing in its description)

I also upgraded to the most recent versions of jquery.multiselect and jquery.multiselect.filter plugins.  When I try to close one of the multiselect menus, I get this error:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
jquery-1.9.1.js (line 9033)
```

Note that although I'm using the multiselect plugin when the error occurs, the actual error is in the main jQuery file.  The code is:

```
/*9031*/ if ( this.options.duration ) {
/*9032*/   this.pos = eased = jQuery.easing[ this.easing ](
/*9033*/     percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration
/*9034*/   );
/*9035*/ }
```

Did I forget to update some file?  Googling about it, others with the same complaint seem to all be trying to use some sort of additional easing plugin, but I'm not.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a publicly available mockup, or minimal working example, that illustrates your problem? It doesn't have to be your live site - just somewhere we can go and get the error message ourselves. If you can reproduce it in jsfiddle.net, that's absolutely enough - if not, then a simple html page with a (very) short script that triggers this problem.

Comment: you may included the jquery file more than once..or check your version is supporting the easing or not..include another version of ui

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the hints.  While preparing something that could be put on jsfiddle, I linked to public files instead of my own copies, and when I linked to Eric Hynds' site for Multiselect, it started working.  I had a version and file naming problem with that file.  Since the errant function call was in the main jquery code file, I kept looking in the wrong places for the problem.

Answer (score 14):

This error could happen in various animations throughout your site when first upgrading to  jQuery 1.9.+  because **the easing effect names have changed !!!**

See http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/
What doesn't help is that the old examples in the jQueryUI.com site havent been updated, leading folks to think that the old animate example names are correct.

**Example:**  accordion panels "bounceslide" animation is now a close version of something called '*easeOutBounce*'. The string "bounceslide" is still in the sites' example as of this writing:
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate.

I only realised the animation names had changed after following the hyperlink mentioned in the animate types and trying the new names out within my code.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in - that may help someone else who finds this thread later.  In my case, though, I wasn't writing code using those effects; I was just using commonly available plugins that were supposed to play together (and they did, once I fixed my references).

Answer (score 10):

Include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Note: update the jquery UI version if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if your point is to suggest use of public sources or just to mention that 1.10.3 is out now (it wasn't yet when I asked my question).  Normally, linking public files can be a good thing (might help with caching), but I "roll my own" jQuery UI, as I said in my question.  Anyway, this thread is old now.

Comment: OsakaWebbie you may right. I should say, Include latest jquery UI library. But I just not replied to answer your question, I just replied coz if someone new to this error will get quick fix.

Comment: This error still (again?) happens with jquery-ui 1.11.4 and jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget 1.14pre

Comment: @AlexChaffee and were you successful to solve it somehow? For me the problem was solved with upgrading `jquery.multiselect.min.js` from version 1.12 to 1.13.

Answer (score 2):

### Invalid 2nd Argument Issue

In case this helps someone stumbling upon this question like I did when I got this error, I'll add another possible solution. My error was due to the fact that my 2nd argument to the `fadeIn` function was not a "callback" function to be executed on completion of the animation. If the 2nd argument is not a function, jQuery expects it to be a type of easing to use. My 2nd argument was mistakenly an object - *I thought it was a function*.

So, for me,

```
return {
  enter: function(element,classes,done){ //classes variable incorrectly added, making done an object
    element.fadeIn(1000,done);
  }
};
```

became:

```
return {
  enter: function(element,done){ //remove classes variable as wasn't right for this situation - done is now a function
    element.fadeIn(1000,done);
  }
};
```

Note, the change in arguments passed into my anonymous `enter` function. Importantly in my case, these variables were AngularJS injections, so the order they were in was important, not so much their name.

Answer (score 2):

The error can be provoked by **argument inversion** when using an effect method wrongly like `.show(duration, easing)` as it leads to a call of an invalid easing.

The correct notation is `.show(easing, duration)` https://api.jquery.com/show/

```js
var duration = 'slow', easing = 'linear';
$("#correct").click(function() {
  $("p").show(duration, easing);
});
$("#error").click(function() {
  $("p").show(easing, duration); // fails -> see error in console
});
```

```css
p { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("p").show(
<button id="correct">duration, easing</button>
<button id="error">easing, duration -> ERROR</button>
)
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
```

Comment: The example on the UI api page and the differences of order of arguments on jq and UI pages is misleading! That's what causes confusions...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Legionar's comment, upgrade to his suggested version `1.13` worked for me:

```
https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/archive/1.13.zip
```

**UPDATE** in this version the usage of `outerHeight()` function causes the widget to position wrong because it misses css position `top`, changing line#573 to following will get the issue fixed:

```
top: pos.top + button.outerHeight(false),
```

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing to do with versions.

I had this code and got the same error:

```
$("#consoleBtn").click(function(){
    $("#consolePanel").toggle("display", {  from : { display: "block" }, to : { display: "none" } });
});
```

The problem was the arguments I passed to the toggle function. So I changed to:

```
$("#consoleBtn").click(function(){
    $("#consolePanel").toggle();
});
```

So be mindful of the arguments passed to your function when calling jQuery-api. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still does not solve the issue as the options are required by the dev