# TypeError: v.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Hi all I make the easing effect for the notification bar in my wordpress Site but whenever i click the button i get the error as TypeError.
TypeError: v.easing[this.easing] is not a function
Here is the script i using now

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In Previously i called the script as like this

```
 <script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the Screenshot What i face exactly.
[image]

Any suggestion would be great. 
I Provide the live [link](http://techstumbling.com/catchy-bar)

Comment: Just like it says, v.easing[this.easing] is not a function, `alert(typeof v.easing[this.easing])` and `alert(this.Easing)` (or console.log instead of alert).

Comment: Maybe it should be `$.easing` or `jQuery.easing`.

Comment: I load the jquery library from wp-includes of wordpress.

Comment: No, the error is from the jQuery file, in which there is "v". jQuery is probably being misused.

Comment: You have two versions of jQuery in your webpage

Comment: No, jQuery UI and jQuery are different files. Make sure that `easeOutBounce` exists in `$.easing`. Besides you seem to be using two different easing on `.animate()`, aren't you ?

Comment: http://techstumbling.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3
and http://techstumbling.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js on your webpage

Comment: @MoazzamKhan both of them same

Comment: @vicky They're the same, but you should only include it exactly **once**. The second jQuery `<script>` overwrites everything done by the first jQuery and jQuery UI `<script>`. That's why you lose jQuery UI's easing extensions.

Comment: @Mattias Buelens Yeah But it is the theme dependent i am not sure how can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: @vicky It seems like you're using the default Twenty Twelve theme, but you placed some customizations in the `<head>` (scripts, styles and even `<div>`s - which is a **very** bad idea). You'll need to post some of your PHP code which inserts these customizations. It looks like your inserting those too early in the HTML and you're not using `wp_enqueue_script/style` (which would ensure only one version of each script was inserted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two copy of jQuery file in your webpage, remove one inclusion, it would start working. I checked it in my system.

Removing line number 200 -

```
script type='text/javascript' src='http://techstumbling.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

would work.

**Explained** -

You have included jQuery file in the following order -

- jQuery - created $ and added few properties to $
- jQuery Ui - added more properties to $
- jQuery - created $ and overridden the jQuery UI specific properties in $

Answer (score 1):

According to the accepted answere of [@Moazzam Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823389/moazzam-khan). I had the same issue using **jQuery 1.8.3** but I was pretty sure that **I have included jQuery only once**. 
After trying around I found out that I have to **include jQuery-UI as well**. Than the issue disappeard. Hope this helps people who experienced the same probpem like I did.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is because the easing effect named was changes after version 1.9 of jQuery.

Link to the solution:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719456/typeerror-jquery-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function-in-jquery-1-9-1)

this is the list of all new easing and theirs names:
http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the big problem is pointed out, you include two time JQuery.
But it's not a big big problem itself.

The bigest problem is that you have an include of JQuery **AFTER** including JQuery-UI.

There's a high probability that the inclusion of JQuery unset some things that Jquery-ui set when your include it. It may explain why your animation option is not found.